# Access multiple datasources with jdbcTemplates in one Service class

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jdbctemplate

Here is my case:
I have two databases: one sybase and one mssql. I wish to access both of the database in a single service class. For example, I want to get some data from sybase, then I need do some update on mssql.

I have setup two datasources based on multiple samples found online, but Im unable to access my second database (sybase).

Here is my code:

> pom.xml

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp


# Database
# spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/database1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://database1/db_aes
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=password1

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# 2nd Database
spring.secondDatasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.secondDatasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sybase://database2/aidcconfig
spring.secondDatasource.username=user2
spring.secondDatasource.password=password2
spring.secondDatasource.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect
spring.secondDatasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.secondDatasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1


# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update, validate)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

com.ibm.websphere.persistence.ApplicationsExcludedFromJpaProcessing=*
```

> fileUploadServiceImpl

```
@Component("fileUploadService")
@Transactional
public class FileUploadServiceImpl implements FileUploadService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dbAesJdbcTemplate")
    JdbcTemplate dbAesJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("aidcconfigJdbcTemplate")
    JdbcTemplate aidcconfigJdbcTemplate;

    private int uploadId = 1;

    private void testDB(){
            String db = aidcconfigJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select db_name()", String.class);
            System.out.println("database name: " + db);
    }
...
}
```

> DbAesDataSource

```
package config.database;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbAesEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "dbAesTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"web.fileUpload.repo.db_aes.dao"}
        )
public class DbAesDataSource {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="dbAesDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dbAesDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="dbAesJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate dbAesJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dbAesDataSource") DataSource dbAesDataSource)
    {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dbAesDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name="dbAesEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbAesEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dbAesDataSource") DataSource dbAesDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dbAesDataSource)
                .packages("web.fileUpload.repo.db_aes.models")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbAesTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbAesTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("dbAesEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory dbAesEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(dbAesEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

> AidcconfigDataSource

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "aidcconfigEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "aidcconfigTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"web.fileUpload.repo.aidcconfig.dao"}
        )
public class AidcconfigDataSource {

    @Bean(name="aidcconfigDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDatasource")
    public DataSource aidcconfigDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="aidcconfigJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate aidcconfigJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("aidcconfigDataSource") DataSource aidcconfigDataSource)
    {
        return new JdbcTemplate(aidcconfigDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name="aidcconfigEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean aidcconfigEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("aidcconfigDataSource") DataSource aidcconfigDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(aidcconfigDataSource)
                .packages("web.fileUpload.repo.aidcconfig.models")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "aidcconfigTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager aidcconfigTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("aidcconfigEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory aidcconfigEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(aidcconfigEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on
 project testUpload: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with
 name 'fileDownloadController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework
.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private web.fileUpload.services.FileUploadService w
eb.fileUpload.controller.FileDownloadController.fileUploadService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fa
ctory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUploadService': Injection of autowired dependencies
 failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org
.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate web.fileUpload.services.FileUploadServiceImpl.dbAesJdbcTemplate; nested exc
eption is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springfr
amework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidat
e for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=tr
ue), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dbAesJdbcTemplate)} -> [Help 1]
```

If I removed the Qualifier in the FileUploadServiceImpl, then any jdbcTemplate will only connect to my Primary database which is db_aes. How can I access to my second datasource using jdbcTemplate?

Following are some of the references I used:
[Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA with multiple DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources)

https://www.infoq.com/articles/Multiple-Databases-with-Spring-Boot

[Multiple DataSource and JdbcTemplate in Spring Boot (> 1.1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755429/multiple-datasource-and-jdbctemplate-in-spring-boot-1-1-0)

**Trial#1**
I noticed that it is unable to create the bean, and I placed some logger in the AidcconfigDataSource class. As a result, I didn't see my method is being executed. Thus, I assumed that the application is not reading my AidcconfigDataSource class.

I relocated the config folder as such, from java/config to java/web/config:

[image]

now I have another error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on
 project testUpload: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with
 name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.spr
ingframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.beans.facto
ry.BeanFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory; nested e
xception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'aidc
configDataSource' defined in class path resource [web/config/database/AidcconfigDataSource.class]: factory-bean ref
erence points back to the same bean definition -> [Help 1]
```

**Trial#2**

I have changed my bean name from aidcconfigDataSource to aidcconfigDS and same to the primary datasource. Plus I have added "spring.jpa.open_in_view = false" in my application.properties. However another error happens.  How to do this the right way?

```
2016-11-03 09:28:16.118 ERROR 11412 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.servic
e() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exce
ption is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springf
ramework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dbAesTransa
ctionManager,aidcconfigTransactionManager] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.
transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dbAesTransactionMana
ger,aidcconfigTransactionManager
```

Comment: Are you using `@Transactional` without specify the name of the transaction manager? Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050183/enabletransactionmanagement-annotation-with-2-transaction-managers maybe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Spring Boot is trying to instantiate 2 beans with the same name:
`aidcconfigDataSource`.

One is your configuration class `AidcconfigDataSource.class` and the other one is the bean:

```
@Bean(name="aidcconfigDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDatasource")
    public DataSource aidcconfigDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

Comment: so... you are saying I should not give the same name for the config class and the Bean, and to solve it, I just need to change the name of the Bean, correct?

Comment: Correct, I think changing the name the previous exception will disapear