# How to add two databases in hikari properties?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

I am using HikariCP and jdbc template to query from one database.The method i use is like below:

My Hikari CP config file(`hikari.properties`):

```
driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.19.99:5432/mvc_data_base
maximumPoolSize=60
dataSource.cachePrepStmts=true
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
```

I do the configuration by this

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig("D:/hikari.properties");
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
    return dataSource;
    }
    }
```

I want to query I do by the JDBC template

```
public class UserDetail {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jtmUserDetail;
         List<Map<String, Object>> row1= 
           jtmUserDetail.queryForList("select * from pubic.user");

}
```

Now I want something like

```
 public class UserDetail {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jtmUserDetail;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jtmUserDetail2;
         List<Map<String, Object>> row1= 
           jtmUserDetail.queryForList("select * from pubic.user");
         List<Map<String, Object>> row2= 
           jtmUserDetail2.queryForList("select * from pubic.user");


}
```

where `jtmUserDetail` is querying from one database(`mvc_data_base`) and `jtmUserDetail2` from another(`test_data_base`).

I am not sure how to specify which database to query here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 datasources properties and 2 functions for getting each datasource as

```
 public DataSource dataSourceSecond() throws SQLException {
  HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig("D:/hikari2.properties");
```

and then add logic to control when to use each of the datasource.

You can use 2 jdbcTemplate with [different @Qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755429/multiple-datasource-and-jdbctemplate-in-spring-boot-1-1-0)

Comment: Ok but how to specify the jdbcTemplate which data source to use?

Comment: See example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755429/multiple-datasource-and-jdbctemplate-in-spring-boot-1-1-0